# What 7400-series logic variants include input clamp diodes?

Tags: level-shifting, esd, 7400

When prototyping, I often use spare 7400-series chips I have lying around. I have a good variety of chips, including many 74HC and 74AHC parts, as well as older varieties like 74LS.

From time to time I like to implement "quick and dirty" 5V to 3V3 level conversion, and one easy way to do this is with by interfacing a 5V signal to a 3V3-powered chip with a current-limiting resistor. The idea here is that the "input protection" clamp diodes present on the inputs of a logic chip will conduct any excess current on the input to VDD, limiting the input voltage to the supply voltage (3V3), accomplishing 5V-to-3V3 conversion on the input with only a single resistor.

I've looked around the web, and I haven't been able to find any resource indicating what 7400-series variants include these diodes on their inputs. Of course I can look at individual datasheets, but I have a suspicion that certain variants (e.g. 74HC) usually include them, while other variants (e.g. 74AHC) may not. (these just are made-up examples)

Does anyone know what the general situation is, or if there is any definitive answer for this? And does it depend on the manufacturer?

Comment: BTW, I am aware of the myriad of ways of doing level shifting, as well as the fact that the method proposed in this question is often an undesirable approach. Never mind that. I just want to know if certain variants generally have "input protection" (clamp) diodes, and other variants generally do not. TI ["Designing With Logic (1997)"](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sdya009c/sdya009c.pdf) seems to indicate that all CMOS devices have them, but I'm not so sure. I seem to recall some 'AHC datasheets warning against _any_ input over VDD, even at minute currents.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your own question, use the "edit" function.

Comment: I didn't want to bloat the original question with (actually) irrelevant details that I suspect some people will nevertheless get hung up on.

Comment: TI documentation for discrete logic products usually includes explicit schematics for all inputs and output drivers. Did you check the datasheets for particular chips you have?

Comment: @AliChen I have checked specific datasheets, but I really want to know if it's something that can be expected (or not) within certain _variants_. IOW e.g., _all_ 'HC chips but _not_ in 'AHC chips. That would simply things when deciding which ones to reach for.

I suppose I could try to do an exhaustive search of all the TI SN74HCxx datasheets, and compare them with the SN74AHCxx datasheets, but I thought to myself "somebody on stackexchange probably already knows the answer". Besides, that would be for just one manufacturer... or maybe it's "standard", but I don't know how to be sure.

Comment: Apparently my data on TI schematics is somewhat outdated. The protection of inputs nowadays is more complicated. Maybe this old appnote might be of some help, http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slya014a/slya014a.pdf

Comment: BTW, for those of you who doubt the _possibility_ that some CMOS 74xx logic variants might lack full input protection (clamp) diodes, see the [TI AHC/AHCT Designer’s Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scla013d/scla013d.pdf), page 10. The input circuit does _not_ include a clamp diode to VDD.

Comment: Actually, there are even more sophisticated protection circuits, using dynamic floating references instead of hard VSS and VDD connections, see this patent for example: https://www.google.ch/patents/US6674622

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NXP's [Logic selection guide](http://www.nxp.com/documents/selection_guide/75017285.pdf) says (p. 18):

> Devices with overvoltage-tolerant inputs do not have
>   input clamp diodes on digital inputs, and can be used
>   to interface to higher-voltage systems without using
>   external current-limiting resistors.
>
> The following families, in alphabetical order, have digital
>   inputs that are overvoltage-tolerant and can be used to
>   interface with subsystems operating at a higher supply
>   voltage: AHC, ALVC, ALVT, AUP, AVC, AXP, CBTLV(D),
>   LVC, and LVT.
>
> [image: over-voltage-tolerant CMOS input]

(So AC(T) and HC(T) *do* have ESD diodes to V<sub>CC</sub>.)

TI's [Logic Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sdyu001), Toshiba's [Logic ICs catalog](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=7426), and Fairchild's [Logic Selection Guide](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/collateral/Logic-Selection-Guide.pdf) also mention voltage tolerance or downtranslation as features of these families.

TI's application report [Input and Output Characteristics of Digital Integrated Circuits at 3.3-V Supply Voltage](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/szza010) shows what actually happens when you go above V<sub>CC</sub> (apparently, (A)LVC have Zener diodes that clamp at a higher voltage).

For devices with ESD diodes, TI's application report [3.3 V I/O Considerations for Hercules™ Safety MCUs in Automotive and Industrial Environments](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/spna087) suggests to use not a simple resistor but a voltage divider (section 3.2).

Comment: Thank you, @CL, for finding a definitive reference (at least for TI), rather than relying on the assumptions of "great personal experience". I suspected that something like this was the case...

Comment: Also,the 2018 TI "Little Logic Guide" indicates that the SN74LV1Txx parts include built in level translation (no resistors needed going up or down).  http://www.ti.com/lit/sg/scyt129g/scyt129g.pdf

Comment: @user4574 LV1T devices are just AHCT devices tested for more supply voltages.